# silverlight chart lineseries "padding"

Tags: silverlight, charts, padding

I have this line series chart which gets populated at run-time, which means programmatically. This is what it looks like now:

[image]

I would like to add some sort of "padding" to the line series, so it looks nicer. It would look something like this: (photoshoped)

[image]

or just:

[image]

I think even more padding would be even better. Kinda like the [finance.yaho](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=MSFT%20Interactive#chart1:symbol=msft;range=1y;indicator=volume;charttype=line;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined)o graphs I guess. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking @vorrtex's answer a bit further, you could bind the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values on both axes to View Model properties (assuming you are using MVVM) and after calculating the points of the line series update these values. So your XAML would become:

```
<chart:Chart.Axes>
    <chart:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Minimum="{Binding XMinimum}" Maximum="{Binding XMaximum}" />
    <chart:LinearAxis Orientation="Y"  Minimum="{Binding YMinimum}" Maximum="{Binding YMaximum}" ShowGridLines="True" />
</chart:Chart.Axes>
```

Comment: I'm a pretty noob programmer. I don't really know MVVM. Can you elaborate a little bit? also, check my second answer ^^

Comment: @JelloCaca - A Q&A is not really the best place to explain this stuff. You are on the right lines but you need to implement the `INotifyProperyChanged` interface. I suggest you do some searches (not just on Stack Overflow) about Model-View-ViewModel. There are some great starter posts on the MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the axes explicitly and set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties.

For your example I would do it so:

```
<chart:Chart>
    <!-- ... -->
    <chart:Chart.Axes>
        <chart:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Minimum="-0.5" Maximum="3.5" />
        <chart:LinearAxis Orientation="Y"  Minimum="0" Maximum="1200" ShowGridLines="True" />
    </chart:Chart.Axes>
</chart:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

@chris, am I on the right track with this?

```
public class Xorientation
{
    private int _XMinimum;
    private int _XMaximum;

    public Xorientation(int Xminimum, int Xmaximum)
    {
        _XMinimum = Xminimum;
        _XMaximum = Xmaximum;
    }

    public int XMinimum
    {
        get { return _XMinimum; }
        set { _XMinimum = value; }
    }

    public int XMaximum
    {
        get { return _XMaximum; }
        set { _XMaximum = value; }
    }
}
```